# Prove that for positive real numbers $a,b,c$ we have $\frac{a}{b+c}+ \frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b} \geq \frac{3}{2}.$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that for positive real numbers $a,b,c$ we have $$\dfrac{a}{b+c}+ \dfrac{b}{a+c}+\dfrac{c}{a+b} \geq \dfrac{3}{2}.$$

**Attempt**

I tried using AM-GM and got $ \dfrac{a}{2\sqrt{bc}}+\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{ac}}+\dfrac{c}{2\sqrt{ab}} \geq \dfrac{a}{b+c}+ \dfrac{b}{a+c}+\dfrac{c}{a+b}$ but that doesn't seem to help since that gives an upper not lower bound.

Comment: As noted in the comments to the "possible duplicate", this is [Nesbitt's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality), and the Wikipedia page has 6 different proofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have by **AM-GM** inequality twice: $\displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyclic}} \dfrac{a}{b+c}=\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyclic}} (a+b)\displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyclic}} \dfrac{1}{a+b}-3\geq \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 3\cdot 3-3=\dfrac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{a+c} +  \frac{c}{a+b} = \frac{a^2}{ab+ac} + \frac{b^2}{ab+bc} +  \frac{c^2}{ac+bc} \geq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2(ab+bc+ac)}$$

Recall Buniakowsky inequality:
$$ (a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2) \geq (ax+by+cz)^2$$
by expanding and regrouping the terms of:
$$(ay-bx)^2 + (az-cx)^2 + (bz - cy)^2 \geq 0$$

So now:
$$ \bigg (\frac{a^2}{x} + \frac{b^2}{y} + \frac{c^2}{z} \bigg )(x+y+z) \geq (a+b+c)^2, \forall x,y,z > 0$$
or
$$ \frac{a^2}{x} + \frac{b^2}{y} + \frac{c^2}{z} \geq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{x+y+z}, \forall x,y,z > 0$$

Comment: How does that prove it?

Comment: Can you try to prove RHS $\geq \frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, but how did you get that $\dfrac{a^2}{ab+ac}+\dfrac{b^2}{ab+bc}+\dfrac{c^2}{ac+bc} \geq \dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{2(ab+bc+ac)}$?

Comment: I will edit my answer